# DataTables JS problem with sum, sum all data only after filter out the other column that not equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How do I apply a filter on a column by searching the column that doesn't have value 'Cerere' or 'Anulat' and with that filtered content, I want to get the sum from another column

```
let total = $('#datatable1').DataTable().data().filter(function (value, index) {
    return (value[8].indexOf("Anulat") !== -1 || value[8].indexOf('Cerere') !== -1) ? false : true;
    })
        .data()
        .column(6, { search: 'applied' }).data().reduce(function (a, b) {
            console.log( parseInt(a),  parseInt(b));
            return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        }, 0);
```

What I want is to sum column 6, but not to sum the rows which have status 'Cerere' on column 8.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
After many tries, I found how to filter data, then pluck the column I wanted, then sum

```js
let total = tableData.rows({search: "applied"}).data().filter( function ( value ) {
       return (value[8].indexOf("Anulat") !== -1 || value[8].indexOf('Cerere') !== -1) ? false : true;
}).pluck(6).sum()
```